# Compile with older libc (version `GLIBC_2.14' not found)

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I have to compile a program on a current ubuntu (12.04). This program should then run on a cluster using CentOS with an older Kernel (2.6.18). I cannot compile on the cluster directly, unfortunately. If I just compile and copy the program without any changes I get the error message "kernel too old".

The way I understood it, the reason for this is not so much the Kernel version, but the version of libc that was used for compilation. So I tried to compile my program dynamically linking the libc from the cluster and statically linking everything else.

**Research**

There are already a lot of questions about this on SO but none of the answers really worked for me. So here is my research on that topic:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941332/anticipate-kernel-too-old-errors-between-2-6-16-and-2-6-26-kernel-versions) explains the reason for the Kernel too old message
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170651/how-do-i-compile-code-for-a-setup-with-older-linux-kernel) is similar but more specialized and has no answers
- Linking statically as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127589/run-a-c-executable-in-another-distro) didn't work because the libc  is too old on the cluster. One answer also mentions to build using the old libc, but doesn't explain how to do this.
- [One way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079717/how-do-i-build-an-app-for-an-old-linux-distribution-and-avoid-the-fatal-kernel) is to compile in a VM running an old OS. This worked but is complicated. I also read that [you should not link libc statically](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2009-07/msg00299.html)
- [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728552/link-to-a-different-libc-file) it [is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099013/link-to-provided-glibc) to compile for a different libc version with the option `-rpath` but this did not work for me (see below)

**Current state**

I copied the following files from the cluster into the directory `/path/to/copied/libs`

- libc-2.5.so
- libgcc_s.so.1
- libstdc++.so.6

and am compiling with the options `-nodefaultlibs -Xlinker -rpath=/path/to/copied/libs -Wl,-Bstatic,-lrt,-lboost_system,-lboost_filesystem -Wl,-Bdynamic,-lc,-lstdc++,-lgcc_s`

The output of ldd on the compiled binary is

```
mybin: /path/to/copied/libs/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by mybin)
mybin: /path/to/copied/libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by mybin)
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff36bb000)
libc.so.6 => /path/to/copied/libs/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbe3789a000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /path/to/copied/libs/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbe37599000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /path/to/copied/libs/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbe3738b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbe37bf3000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbe37071000)
```

I'm somewhat confused by the error, because it uses the correct path (i.e. the libc from the cluster) but still complains about a missing glibc version. When running ldd on the cluster it returns `not a dynamic executable` and running the binary results in the same two errors mentioned above. It also looks like there are other libraries included (linux-vdso.so.1, ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and libm.so.6). Should I use the older versions for those as well?

So now I have two main questions:

- Is this even the correct approach here?
- If yes: how do I link the old libc correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8658468/50617) answer.

> Is this even the correct approach here

No: you can't use *mismatched* versions of glibc as your link command does. You used `crt0.o` and `ld-linux.so` from *new* (system-installed) libc, but `libc.so.6` from an old (copied from cluster) libc. That is just not going to work.

Answer (score 3):

`-rpath` sets the DT_RPATH tag but doesn't tell the linker to look there for libs, you want `-L` for that.