# Installing Light Table on CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, lighttable

When trying to run Light table on my CentOS 6.5 I get this message:

`` /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found ``

I dont want to install a newer glibc from source since I'm afraid to break other systems using the older version. Any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting the same problem and, according to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815453/compile-with-older-libc-version-glibc-2-14-not-found) there's no way around it. LightTable was compiled with more recent libraries that CentOS doesn't ship with. The alternative seems to build node-webkit from source (as stated on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable)) but I haven't tried that yet. If I find a better solution I will update my reply.

Answer (score -1):

[Compiling](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/164) fixed it for me.

They seem to have compiled it with an older version of `gligc` now.