# Importing MySQLdb and `GLIBC_2.14' not found

Tags: python, mysql, centos, mysql-python, glibc

Trying to run a Python script that imports MySQLdb. I've ran `yum update libgcrypt`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/python/ig/ig-post.py", line 12, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/user/.linuxbrew/lib/libcrypt.so.1)
```

Also maybe helpful:

```
# yum info libgcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * epel: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * extras: centos.mirror.fr.planethoster.net
 * updates: centos.quelquesmots.fr
Installed Packages
Name        : libgcrypt
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.4.5
Release     : 12.el6_8
Size        : 524 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : A general-purpose cryptography library
URL         : http://www.gnupg.org/
License     : LGPLv2+
Description : Libgcrypt is a general purpose crypto library based on the code used
            : in GNU Privacy Guard.  This is a development version.

Available Packages
Name        : libgcrypt
Arch        : i686
Version     : 1.4.5
Release     : 12.el6_8
Size        : 228 k
Repo        : base
Summary     : A general-purpose cryptography library
URL         : http://www.gnupg.org/
License     : LGPLv2+
Description : Libgcrypt is a general purpose crypto library based on the code used
            : in GNU Privacy Guard.  This is a development version.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile with older libc (version \`GLIBC\_2.14' not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815453/compile-with-older-libc-version-glibc-2-14-not-found)

Comment: @EmployedRussian That question is different, given that it says what he did wrong, but it doesn't say what to do to actually fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a locally-built `/home/user/.linuxbrew/lib/libcrypt.so.1` which has been built on a system with GLIBC-2.14 (or newer).

That library is *incompatible* with the system you are trying to run on (which has GLIBC-2.13 or older).

You need to either remove `/home/user/.linuxbrew/lib` from your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or whatever mechanism you use to pick it up), or remove `/home/user/.linuxbrew/lib/libcrypt.so.1` altogether.